# I want to run coded UI test cases on different windows OS, do i need to install vsvt on all of them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I create a coded ui test case and I want to run this cases on different locale/platforms, like ENU XP, JPN Win7.
Do I need to install vsvt on all the clients? I think the answer is NO, but what are the other ways?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to install the Visual Studio Test Agent on the machines you want to run the tests on.

More info about Test Agents and Controllers is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293551.aspx

Test Agent download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1334

And finally, configuring Test Agents with Coded UI Testing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx

Hope this helps :)